# iPhoto 9.4.2 crashes on startup and reboots MacBook Pro 10.8.2

Tags: macos, photos.app

When I attempt to open iPhoto (9.4.2) on my MacBook Pro (10.8.2) iPhoto crashes and it reboots my laptop. iPhoto will open if I boot the MacBook Pro in safe mode.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Does this happen with every photo library? If you rename the current library, iPhoto will create a new one. Does it start correctly this way?

Comment: No need to rename anything, just hold down the option (or alt) key key and launch iPhoto. From the resulting menu select 'Create Library'...

Comment: Safe mode has isolated the crash to a non-essential or third party extension. You might also avoid the issue by making a new user account and testing iPhoto with a clean library. If that doesn't crash then you know it's not just iPhoto, but your iPhoto library and the system that are colliding.

Comment: You most likely have a broken driver.  Given the application, it is most likely one of those that talks to cameras.

Answer (score 2):

This link to Apple's Support page on Safe Boot, or Safe Mode, details what what is loaded and what is not, and may point you to possible problem areas.
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564

But more details would be helpful. Which MacBook Pro, whether you've repaired disk, what manintenance utilities you run. Often, with crashing apps, removing its Preferences file cures the problem. Sometimes--not often, but sometimes--a fresh install of the app is the solution.

Also check your Crash Reports for clues--and google the problem as well. Of all Mountain Lion Apple apps, iPhoto is certainly the touchiest. If you have Photostream turned on, try temporarily turning that off.